# What is the function of the Entry statement?

Tags: java, linked-list

So I'm really new when it comes to lists and I'm wondering if I've understood the following code correctly, and more specifically what the function of the `Entry` statement is.

Is it because of the `Entry` statement that myList is capable of accepting the entries from myHashMap in order to later sort the list with the comparator?

```
   List<Entry<String, Integer>> myList = new LinkedList<Entry<String, Integer>>(myHashMap.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1, Entry<String, Integer> o2){

            return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }

    });
```

Comment: **HasMap** stores element in form of **Entry** objects, and as you are creating a list for holding **Entry** objects, your list has accepted the entry set from **HashMap**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because of the Entry statement that myList is capable of accepting the entries from myHashMap in order to later sort the list with the comparator?

Exactly!

A `HashMap` as you know, has a structure like this:

```
{
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    key3: value3,
    ...
}
```

Each KVP is called an `Entry`. In other words, a `HashMap` can be represented by a set of `Entry` objects. And that is exactly what the `entrySet` method does. You use `entrySet` to get all the KVPs as `Entry` objects, put them in a list and sort them.